# post_controller_constructor Hooks redirection isseus in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, hook

hello all can any one help me to solve out this redirect issues in codeigniter.
i create a hook for login authentication .

below is my hook

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_auth {

    function __construct() {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
         if (!class_exists('session'))
        {
            $this->CI->load->library('session');
        }            
    }

    function auth(){                                   
        if(! $this->CI->session->userdata('islogin')
        {
            redirect(base_url().'loginCtrl/index');
        }
    }
```

the purpose to create hook is when i try to enter any url when not logged in it should redirect to login page

but it shows webpage has redirect loop

Comment: which is your controller name of this  code

Comment: controller name is loginCtrl.php

Answer (score 0):

It will have a redirect loop as it's checking every page for a session. Including the login page.

You could do something like this;

```
if(!$this->CI->session->userdata('islogin')) {
    // Not logged in. Are they trying to login?
    if(!in_array($this->CI->uri->uri_string(), array('login', 'forgot-password')))
    {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

This will check if the user is logged in. If their not, it will check the current uri_string and compare it to an array of "allowed" uri's `array('login', 'forgot-password')`

Hope this helps.

Comment: but what is array('login','forgot-password')

Comment: `array('login','forgot-password')` is the array of URI's the user can visit without been logged in.

Comment: but  i have to allow visit only login page

Comment: So then delete `'forgot-password'` from the array?

Comment: Replace 'login' with 'loginCtrl' and see what happens.

Comment: it will also stop to redirect any page after login